# XSLT: Append Children to Already Created Nodes in the Output Document

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

In a specific case in my program, I need to append new children to nodes that have already been created in the output document. For example in the following OUTPUT xml, when applying a template to create 'Child-Three' node, append some new children to 'Child-One' and 'Child-Two':

```
<Root>    
    <Parent>
       <Child-One/>
       <Child-Two/>
       <Child-Three/>
    </Parent>    
</Root>
```

I don't know if it is even possible to go back to already created nodes, but would save me a lot of time...

Comment: My question would be what type of knowledge you have at the end that you don't have in the the beginning? During the processing of the input you are always free to "peek" ahead as often as you need. So why not insert the nodes right away?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the answer is that you can only write to a tree sequentially. But you can of course do a multi-phase transformation where you write a tree, and then transform it again. There are two ways to do this: separate transformations, or separate phases within a single transformation. (This is known as "pipelining", and is a powerful way of building complex transformations from simple reusable parts).